# How to analyse the ratio of two continuous variables sampled repeatedly over time

Tags: repeated-measures, mixed-model, small-sample, ratio

I am measuring reproductive hormones in dolphins over time to look at seasonal changes.  The sample type (respiratory vapour) that I am using suffers from variable water dilution that cannot easily be quantified (an artefact of normal respiratory processes).  For this reason, absolute concentrations are not a consistent measure; however, dilution will affect all analytes in respiratory vapour equally, therefore comparing the ratio of key hormones, which are biologically important, will indicate when/how changes are occurring over time.

This is an example of my experimental design, where XX is progesterone (ng/mL)/oestradiol (ng/mL)
e.g.

```
Dolphin ID        Sex         Time point         Progesterone:oestradiol
 1                  F              1                     XX
```

My sample size will be small (i.e. 12 animals) and sampling will occur over 4 time periods.  For this reason, I don't think I will have the statistical power to analyse these using standard parametric tests (mixed effects model with repeated measures).

Any information in regards to what kind of statistical analysis would be useful or any transformations of this ratio data to conform to traditional tests would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although your sample size is relatively small, I see no reason in principle why you cannot perform a 'traditional' mixed models analysis. The small sample size will simply affect the power of your analysis to detect real differences, not the validity of the test *per* *se*. Moreover, taking the ratio seems like a valid approach given your worries about the absolute concentration variability.